# how to grep large number of files?

Tags: bash, grep

I am trying to `grep` 40k files in the current directory and i am getting this error.

```
for i in $(cat A01/genes.txt); do grep $i *.kaks; done > A01/A01.result.txt
-bash: /usr/bin/grep: Argument list too long
```

How do one normally `grep` thousands of files?

Thanks
Upendra

Comment: I think you use `find` instead

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This makes David sad...

Everyone so far is wrong (except for [anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23573124/368630)).

Shell scripting is not like any other programming language because much of the interpretation of lines comes from the power of the shell interpolating them before the command is actually executed.

Let's take something simple:

```
$ set -x
$ ls
+ ls
bar.txt foo.txt fubar.log
$ echo The text files are *.txt
echo The text files are *.txt
> echo The text files are bar.txt foo.txt
The text files are bar.txt foo.txt
$ set +x
$
```

The `set -x` allows you to see how the shell actually interpolates the glob and then passes that back to the command as input. The `>` points to the line that is actually being executed by the command.

You can see that the `echo` command isn't interpreting the `*`. Instead, the shell grabs the `*` and replaces it with the names of the matching files. Then and only then does the `echo` command actually executes the command.

When you have 40K plus files, and you do `grep *`, you're expanding that `*` to the names of those 40,000 plus files before `grep` even has a chance to execute, and that's where the error message */usr/bin/grep: Argument list too long* is coming from.

Fortunately, Unix has a way around this dilemma:

```
$ find . -name "*.kaks" -type f -maxdepth 1 | xargs grep -f A01/genes.txt
```

The `find . -name "*.kaks" -type f -maxdepth 1` will find all of your `*.kaks` files, and the `-depth 1` will only include files in the current directory. The `-type f` makes sure you only pick up files and not a directory.

The `find` command pipes the names of the files into `xargs` and `xargs` will append the names of the file to the `grep -f A01/genes.txt`command. However, `xargs` has a trick up it sleeve. It knows how long the command line buffer is, and will execute the `grep` when the command line buffer is full, then pass in another series of file to the `grep`. This way, `grep` gets executed maybe three or ten times (depending upon the size of the command line buffer), and all of our files are used.

Unfortunately, `xargs` uses whitespace as a separator for the file names. If your files contain spaces or tabs, you'll have trouble with `xargs`. Fortunately, there's another fix:

```
$ find . -name "*.kaks" -type f -maxdepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0 grep -f A01/genes.txt
```

The `-print0` will cause `find` to print out the names of the files not separated by newlines, but by the NUL character. The `-0` parameter for `xargs` tells `xargs` that the file separator isn't whitespace, but the NUL character. Thus, fixes the issue.

You could also do this too:

```
$ find . -name "*.kaks" -type f -maxdepth 1 -exec grep -f A01/genes.txt {} \;
```

This will execute the `grep` for each and every file found instead of what `xargs` does and only runs `grep` for all the files it can stuff on the command line. The advantage of this is that it avoids shell interference entirely. However, it may or may not be less efficient.

What would be interesting is to experiment and see which one is more efficient. You can use `time` to see:

```
$ time find . -name "*.kaks" -type f -maxdepth 1 -exec grep -f A01/genes.txt {} \;
```

This will execute the command and then tell you how long it took. Try it with the `-exec` and with `xargs` and see which is faster. Let us know what you find.

Comment: +1 hats off to the enormous time you have invested in explaining this.

Comment: Yeah, and you came up with a correct answer while I was in the middle of it. Right before I posted, I had to make a quick edit in my _everybody is wrong_ statement.

Comment: @David....thanks a lot for detailed explanation. I running the two ways and timing them and will update as soon as i finish...

Comment: I was waiting for someone to post the right answer but seeing all other flawed answers I posted a quick one.

Comment: @DavidW. If you are concerned about speed, shouldn't you be using the `-exec command {} +` form, at least on the systems that support it?

Comment: @John1024 Thanks for letting me know about that `+` form of the `find`. I never saw that before. Yes, according to the manpage: ***Same as -exec, except that ``{}'' is replaced with as many pathnames as possible for each invocation of utility. This behavior is similar to that of xargs(1).***. It's what happens when you learn things from 20 years ago, and don't keep up with the changes.

Comment: Just a update. I used `xargs` method that @DavidW. suggested and it worked pretty fast `time find . -name "*.kaks" -type f -maxdepth 1 | xargs grep -f A01/genes.txt > A01/A01.result.txt` 
`real     4m36.566s
user     2m2.835s
sys     0m6.023s ` However the other method w/o `xargs` doesn't seem to be doing anything (not filling up the output file). Been running for more than 20 min without any output...Probably i will stick with the `xarg` method of now. Thanks @DavidW. again..

Comment: My answer is not actually wrong, it is only inefficient. The OP did not mention performance, he mentioned that he had an error with his argument list being too long, and my answer addressed the issue he raised. If an efficient answer is required, the OP should consider GNU Parallel so all his 8 or so CPU cores can do something useful instead of a the sequential methods everyone has suggested.

Comment: I guess there's a question on how BASH uses `for i in *.kah`. Does Bash see the `*.kah` and fill it in with all the files that match, then run the `for` loop. This is how Bourne and Kornshell operate. If so, you'll end up overloading the command line in the `for` loop just as you would if you did `grep *.kah`. If Bash operates the `for` in another way, it may be fine. I would have to play around with `for` loops on Bash and see how `for` gets filled in.

Answer (score 7):

You can combine `find` with `grep` like this:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.kaks' -exec grep -H -f A01/genes.txt '{}' \; > A01/A01.result.txt
```

Comment: This answer nicely solves both potential problems: it avoids (a) expanding `cat A01/genes.txt` on the command line and it avoids (b) expanding `*.kaks` on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

you can use recursive feature of `grep`:

```
for i in $(cat A01/genes.txt); do 
    grep -r $i .
done > A01/A01.result.txt
```

though if you want to select only `kaks` files:

```
for i in $(cat A01/genes.txt); do 
    find . -iregex '.*\.kaks$' -exec grep $i \;
done > A01/A01.result.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Put another for loop inside your outer one:

```
for f in *.kaks; do
   grep -H  $i "$f"
done
```

By the way, are you interested in finding EVERY occurrence in each file, or merely if the search string exists in there one or more times? If it is "good enough" to know the string occurs in there one or more times you can specify "-n 1" to grep and it will not bother reading/searching the rest of the file after finding the first match, which could potentially save lots of time.

Comment: i used the method suggested my @David and it worked fine. Thanks for the alternative...

Answer (score 0):

The following solution has worked for me:

Problem:

```
 grep -r "example\.com" *
 -bash: /bin/grep: Argument list too long
```

Solution:

```
grep -r "example\.com" .
```

["In newer versions of grep you can omit the “.“, as the current directory is implied."]

Source:
Reinlick, J. https://www.saotn.org/bash-grep-through-large-number-files-argument-list-too-long/